# Поиск подстроки в массиве строк и вывод совпадений

Tags: java, строки, поиск, подстрока

Задача такая: на вход файл, найти строки с совпадением с подстрокой и вывести их. Метод contains не использовать. Всё никак не пойму, как сделать его аналог. Ниже код, который есть:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = readFile("./src/text.txt");
        System.out.println(text);
        String[] linelList = text.split("\n");

        System.out.println("Введите подстроку для поиска");

        String substring = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(substring);


    }

    private static String readFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        File file = new File(filename);
        // создаем объект FileReader для объекта File
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        // создаем BufferedReader с существующего FileReader для построчного считывания
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        // считываем сначала первую строку
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

            //lines.add(line);
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
            // считываем остальные строки в цикле
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void saveWords(Map<String, Integer> words, String str) {
        // перебираем строки
        String[] wordsList = str.split("\\s+");
        // перебираем слова строки
        for (String currentWord : wordsList) {
            // приводим текущее слово в нижний регистр
            currentWord = currentWord.toLowerCase();
            // 1 раз это слово встретилось сейчас
            int count = 1;
            // если слово уже встречалось (добавлено в мапу)
            if (words.containsKey(currentWord)) {
                // то прибавляем кол-во встреч с этим словом к общему кол-ву
                count += words.get(currentWord);
            }

            // сохраняем слово в словарь(если уже встречалось, то обновляем информацию)
            words.put(currentWord, count);
        }
    }

    private static void printResult(List<String> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(list.get(i) + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    

}
```

Конкретно не могу понять, как сделать метод, сравнивающий символы. В принципе идею я понял: в цикле сделать проход по строкам в массиве, проверить их на наличие подстроки и вывести.
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Запрещен только метод `String::contains` или **все стандартные методы** типа `String::indexOf`, `String::matches`, поиск при помощи регулярных выражений?  Если приемлема только собственная реализация, можете изучить [алгоритм Кнута - Морриса - Пратта (КМП)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0), который решает задачу эффективного поиска подстроки в строке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну первая идея, которая приходит в голову, так это использовать "скользящий" хеш для поиска подстроки в строке. Алгоритм примерно следующий:

1. Если длина строки меньше длины подстроки, возвращаем `false`.
2. Если длина подстроки равна нулю, возвращаем `true` (пустая подстрока входит во все строки).
3. Вычисляем хеш подстроки и хеш первых N символов строки (N - длина подстроки).
4. В цикле по символам строки обновляем хеш для очередных N её символов и сравниваем с хешем подстроки. Если совпадение, то посимвольно сравниваем с подстрокой. Если все символы совпадают, возвращаем `true`.
5. Возвращаем `false`.

Сразу оговорюсь, я не знаток Java, и следующий код писал с большой оглядкой на мой родной C++. Так что прошу строго не судить, если что. Демонстрирует работу метода `myContains()` - аналог метода `contains()`.

```
class Main
{
    public static boolean myContains(String str, String subStr)
    {
        int strLen = str.length();
        int subLen = subStr.length();
        if (strLen < subLen) return false;
        if (subLen == 0) return true;

        short strHash = 0;
        short subHash = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<subLen; )
        {
            subHash^= subStr.charAt(i); 
            if ((++i) == subLen) break;
            strHash^= str.charAt(i-1);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<strLen-subLen+1; ++i)
        {
            strHash^= str.charAt(i+subLen-1);

            if (strHash == subHash)
            {
                int j = 0;
                for (; j<subLen; ++j)
                    if (str.charAt(i+j) != subStr.charAt(j)) break;
                if (j == subLen) return true;
            }

            strHash^= str.charAt(i);
        }

        return false;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "Java String Contains() Tutorial";

        System.out.println(myContains(str, "Java"));        //true
        System.out.println(myContains(str, "String"));      //true
        System.out.println(myContains(str, "Java String Contains() Tutorial0")); //false
        System.out.println(myContains(str, "Tutorial"));    //true
        System.out.println(myContains(str, " "));           //true
        System.out.println(myContains(str, "Python"));      //false
        System.out.println(myContains(str, ""));            //true
    }
}
```